# JSON Angular Array pulling data from 3rd Loop

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I am struggling to pull the data from the 3rd loop (Names) in the array below.

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

sample.json

```
{
  "otc": [
    {
      "name": "Tums",
      "language": [
        {
          "title": "English",
          "names": [
            {"name": "Tums"},
            {"name": "Pepto"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "China"
        },
        {
          "title": "Germany"
        }
        ,
        {
          "title": "Mexico"
        }
        ,
        {
          "title": "India"
        }
        ,
        {
          "title": "United Kingdom"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Dramamine",
      "language": [
        {
          "title": "title2album1"

        },
        {
          "title": "title2album2"
        },
        {
          "title": "title2album3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my index.html

```
<body ng-app="list">

  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat-start="meds in otc">
      <strong> {{meds.name}}</strong> //This displays just fine 
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="lang in meds.language"><em>{{lang.title}}</em></li> //This displays just fine

    <li ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="drugs in lang.names">{{drugs.name}}</li> //This doesnt display
  </ul>
  </div>

  <script>
  angular.module('list', []);
    function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {
      $http({method: 'GET', url: 'sample.json'}).success(function(data) {
          $scope.otc = [];
          angular.forEach(data.otc, function(value, key) {
              $scope.otc.push(value);
          });
          $scope.isVisible = function(name){
              return true;
          };
        });
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your JSON data is a bit incomplete, since you're missing the `names` key in all of the language objects except for the `English` one.

Beyond that, your html/angular-view code is a bit off.  The ng-repeat's should be nested inside of one-another.  This is done by having the opening/closing html tags that contain the `ng-repeat` directive  completely surround the inner `<li>` tags.

It's a bit hard to tell, but if you want nested lists, you need to add `<ul>` tags like in my example below.

I believe your index html should look something like:

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="meds in otc">
      <strong> {{meds.name}}</strong> //This displays just fine 
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="lang in meds.language">
                <em>{{lang.title}}</em>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="drugs in lang.names">{{drugs.name}}</li>
                </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

The reason why the `li ng-repeat` tags should be nested is because `ng-repeat` creates its own isolate scope.  Which means that inside of an ng-repeat tag, it only has access to the data made available by the ng-repeat="data in datar" part.

So having:

```
<li ng-repeat="lang in meds.language"><em>{{lang.title}}</em></li> //This displays just fine
<li ng-repeat="drugs in lang.names">{{drugs.name}}</li> //This doesnt display
```

as sibling elements, and not the second as a child of the other, the 2nd ng-repeat list does not know what the var `lang` is.  So the `drugs in lang.names` fails.

Btw, this snippet assumes that the output you want is:

- Tums

  - English

    - Tums
    - Pepto
  - China
  - Germany
  - etc
- Dramamine

  - title2album1
  - title2album2
  - etc

If you wanted the output as a flat list, you can use the following CSS

```
ul ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Comment: I like your approach, however, maybe add some CSS code to get the list looking like it was a non-nested list to get the output to look like @Travis original HTML. You won't need the ng-repeat-start or ng-repeat-end in your case either, you can just use ng-repeat and it keeps everything nice and simple.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for i had no idea that they needed to be nested like that for them to know what the other had going on LOL :) Cheers much appreciated